# Determinant of induced metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

I've got the following set up for the induced metric:
[image]

How can I see that the determinant of such induced metric is the one from the following expression?[image]

Comment: Source of images?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06808